# Calculating $\pi_2$ of a certain free loop space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For a topological space $X$, define $LX$ to be the set of continuous maps $S^1 \rightarrow X$ with the compact-open topology. Henceforth let $X = \Bbb{CP}^\infty \times \Bbb{RP}^\infty$, with basepoint $([1:0:\dots], [1:0:\dots])$. Inspired by [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979857/when-is-the-free-loop-space-simply-connected/979866?noredirect=1#comment2008295_979866), I tried to calculate $\pi_1(LX)$. During the calculation I found that $\pi_2(LX) = \Bbb Z$ or $\pi_2(LX) = 0$; in the former case, $\pi_1(LX)$ is finite, and in the latter case, it's a semidirect product of $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. So I'd like to know which of these $\pi_2$ is.

Is there any way to calculate whether or not $\pi_2(LX)$ is nontrivial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbb{CP}^{\infty} \times \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$, being a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces $B^2 \mathbb{Z} \times B \mathbb{Z}_2$, is in particular a loop space and hence is homotopy equivalent to a topological group $G$ (in fact a topological *abelian* group). As I mentioned in the other thread, for any topological group $G$ the free loop space splits as a product (of spaces)

$$LG \cong G \times \Omega G$$

(sketch: fix a point in $S^1$, and evaluate a map $S^1 \to G$ on it; this gives you a point in $G$ and a based loop at that point. But on a topological group $G$ you can canonically translate this based loop to a based loop at the identity), and so we can compute its first two homotopy groups to be

$$\pi_1(LG) \cong \pi_1(G) \times \pi_2(G), \pi_2(LG) \cong \pi_2(G) \times \pi_3(G).$$

In particular, $\pi_2(LG) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(LG) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}$ is a direct product, not a semidirect product.

In general, suppose $X$ is a (pointed) space and we'd like to compute the homotopy groups of $LX$ (based at the constant loop at the basepoint of $X$). There is a nice trick we can play here which I didn't mention in the previous thread because I hadn't figured it out yet: it turns out that the operation of taking based and free loops commute, so that

$$\Omega LX \cong L \Omega X$$

so now we can use the fact that $\Omega X$, being a loop space, is homotopy equivalent to a topological group and hence that its free loop space splits, at least up to homotopy, as a product (of spaces)

$$\Omega LX \cong L \Omega X \cong \Omega X \times \Omega^2 X.$$

Applying $\pi_i, i \ge 1$, we conclude that

$$\pi_{i+1}(LX) \cong \pi_{i+1}(X) \times \pi_{i+2}(X), i \ge 1$$

So that takes care of $\pi_2$ and higher. For $\pi_1$ I suspect, but am not yet sure how to prove, that it is the semidirect product

$$\pi_1(LX) \cong \pi_2(X) \rtimes \pi_1(X)$$

(the action of $\pi_1$ on $\pi_2$ is trivial in the example you give), and for $\pi_0$ we can say the following: $\pi_0(LX)$ breaks up based on the connected component in $\pi_0(X)$ that a given loop is based in, and in each connected component the free homotopy classes of loops are identified with the set of conjugacy classes in the fundamental group $\pi_1(X, x)$ based at any $x$ in the component.

Comment: Okay, I know how to prove that semidirect product decomposition now. First, with all the other $\pi_k$ computed, you can show that two important boundary maps in the long exact sequence in homotopy associated to the fibration $\Omega X \to LX \to X$ vanish (assume $X$ path-connected here or else I have to specify which basepoint I take based loops at), giving a short exact sequence $\pi_2(X) \to \pi_1(LX) \to \pi_1(X)$. Second, the inclusion $X \to LX$ of constant loops into all loops is a splitting of this sequence.

Comment: Ah, the fact that Eilenberg-Maclane spaces are loopspaces eluded me. Thanks for pointing that out (and the rest of the answer, too).

Comment: Incidentally, the simplest example of a space I know with nontrivial action of $\pi_1$ on $\pi_2$ is $X = \mathbb{RP}^2$, where $\pi_1 = \mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on $\pi_2 = \mathbb{Z}$ by reversing signs. So there's your interesting semidirect product.

Comment: Okay, strictly speaking that first comment only shows that we get *some* semidirect product decomposition, not that we get the one associated to the usual action of $\pi_1$ on $\pi_2$. But this probably comes from thinking a bit harder about how the fibration $\Omega X \to LX \to X$ works (which I haven't, yet).

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little suspicious of what I said now, because when I claimed to compute the higher homotopy groups of $LX$ I didn't specify what connected component of $LX$ I was working in, and in particular I didn't specify a free homotopy class of loops in $X$...

Comment: Okay, I think the only thing that needs fixing is my claim about $\pi_1$, which should be modified as follows: fix a connected component $X_0$ of $X$ and a free homotopy class $g$ of loop in $X_0$. Then I believe that $\pi_1(LX, g)$ is the semidirect product of $\pi_2(X_0)$ and the centralizer of a representative of $g$ in $\pi_1(X_0)$.

Comment: You can also look directly at the long exact sequence of homotopy groups induced by the fibration and use the splitting as you did. This takes care of the higher homotopy groups. Interpreting carefully the "exactness" at the fringed end at the bottom (pi_1 acting on pi_0 etc.) gives you the claim about pi_1 of LX.