# What are the maps in the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for the free loop space fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $(X,x)$ be a pointed connected CW complex, and let $\mathcal L X = Map(S^1, X)$ be its free loop space. We have a fibration $\mathcal L X \to X$ given by evaluating at the basepoint $0 \in S^1$, whose fiber is the pointed loop space $\Omega_{x} X$ based at $x$. Let $\lambda \in \mathcal L X$ be a basepoint; we may assume without loss of generality that $\lambda(0)= x$. Then properly speaking, we have a fibration sequence of pointed spaces:

$$(\Omega_{x} X, \lambda) \to (\mathcal L X, \lambda) \to (X,x)$$

We get a long exact sequence in homotopy. The end of it looks like this:

$$\dots \to \pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_0(\Omega_{x} X, \lambda) \to \pi_0(\mathcal L X, \lambda) \to 0$$

Now, I'm told that $\pi_0(\mathcal L X)$ is in bijection with the conjugacy classes of elements of $\pi_1(X)$. Because the middle term is in canonical bijection with $\pi_1(X, x)$,

- This leads me to guess that the map $\pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_0(\Omega_{x} X, \lambda)$ is $\gamma \mapsto \gamma \lambda \gamma^{-1}$.

If that's the case, then the kernel of this map is the centralizer $Z_{\pi_1(X,x)}(\lambda)$. So the next part of the long exact sequence is:

$$ \dots \to \pi_2(X,x) \to \pi_1(\Omega_x X, \lambda) \to \pi_1(\mathcal L X, \lambda) \to Z_{\pi_1(X)}(\lambda) \to 0$$

I don't know what the map $\pi_2(X,x) \to \pi_1(\Omega_x X, \lambda)$ is:

- The natural guess is that this map is $\beta \mapsto \beta^\lambda$ where this denotes the natural action of $\pi_1(X,x)$ on $\pi_2(X,x)$.

But this map is an isomorphism; if this pattern were to persist to higher homotopy groups, it would imply that $\mathcal L X$ is aspherical, and that can't be true -- for instance, the path components of constant loops contain $X$ as a retract, and $X$ need not be aspherical. So I don't think this guess can be correct.

**Question:** Are either of the bulleted statements above correct? If not, is there a good description of the map $\pi_{n+1}(X,x) \to \pi_n(\Omega_x X, \lambda)$ in the long exact sequence of the free loop space fibration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fibration sequence in question is the evaluation sequence

$$\dots\rightarrow\Omega X\xrightarrow{\Delta_\lambda}Map^*_\lambda(S^1,X)\rightarrow Map_\lambda(S^1,X)\xrightarrow{e} X$$

Here the subscript $\lambda$ denotes the path component of $\lambda$ in the mapping spaces, $e$ is the basepoint evaluation map and $\Delta_\lambda$ is the fibration connecting map, which depends very much on the particular choice of $\lambda$. In your notation this is exactly

$$\dots \rightarrow X\xrightarrow{\Delta_\lambda}\Omega_\lambda X\rightarrow\mathcal{L}_\lambda X\xrightarrow{e}X.$$

I'm afraid this notation is a little distinct from yours: here $\Omega_\lambda X$ denotes the path component of the loop $\lambda$ in $\Omega X$, and $\Omega_0 X$ denote the path component of the constant loop in $X$. We're carrying round the basepoint $x\in X$ implicitly here, and all loops are to be based at $X$. Mixing notations we have $\pi_n(\Omega_\lambda X)=\pi_n(\Omega_xX;\lambda)$ (I'll stick to the former).

Now note that the homomorphisms you are studying are exactly those induced by the connecting map $\Delta_\lambda$. And here you're in luck, since this situation has been studied by both Whitehead and Lang. I'll point you towards Lang's paper *The Evaluation Map and EHP Sequences* for further details than I include below, since I have this reference to hand.

Now $\Omega X$ is a grouplike H-space, so all of its path components have the same homotopy type. In particular the right translation map

$$\Omega_\lambda X\rightarrow \Omega_0X,\qquad \omega\mapsto \omega\lambda^{-1}$$

is a homotopy equivalence. If we insert this transformation into the evaluation fibration the connecting map becomes a map

$$P_\lambda:\Omega X\xrightarrow{\Delta_\lambda} \Omega_\lambda X\xrightarrow{\simeq}\Omega_0X.$$

The utility of this is that $\pi_n(\Omega_0X)=\pi_nX$ (I'm assuming wlog that $X$ is path connected), so with these identifications our long exact sequence is

$$\dots\pi_nX\xrightarrow{P_\lambda}\pi_{n}X\rightarrow \pi_{n-1}\mathcal{L}_\lambda X\xrightarrow{e_*} \pi_{n-1}X\rightarrow\dots$$

and Lang tells us

> The homomorphism $P_\lambda$ is the Whitehead product $\alpha\mapsto [\alpha,\lambda]$.

In particular your first map is correct, since on $\pi_1$ the Whitehead product in question is $[\alpha,\lambda]=\alpha\lambda\alpha^{-1}\lambda^{-1}$ (recall our translation map).

So hopefully now you know what the map at $\pi_2$ is, and more generally what the map at $\pi_n$ is.