# Loop group of U(1)

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory, infinite-groups

The loop group of $U(1)$, $LU(1)$ is the space of maps from the circle, $S^1$ to $U(1)$. The based loop group of $U(1)$, $\Omega U(1)$ is the space of based maps from the circle, $S^1$ to $U(1)$. It is known that for a topological space X,

\begin{equation}
\pi_{n-1} (\Omega X)\cong \pi_n (X) .
\end{equation}

This implies that 
\begin{equation}
\pi_{0} (\Omega U(1))\cong\pi_1 (U(1))\cong \mathbb{Z}  ,
\end{equation}
which means that $\Omega U(1)$ is not path connected.
Next, note that 
\begin{equation}
LU(1)\cong\Omega U(1) \times U(1)
\end{equation}
(as spaces, not topological groups; note that this relation holds for loop groups of topological groups, but not necessarily for other loop spaces in general). Then
\begin{equation}
\pi_{0} (L U(1))\cong\pi_{0} (\Omega U(1)) \times \pi_{0}(U(1))\cong \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
which means the loop group of $U(1)$ is not path connected either.

Let's write the elements of $U(1)$ as
\begin{equation}
e^{i\lambda}.
\end{equation}
I can then write the elements of $L U(1)$ explicitly as
\begin{equation}
e^{i\lambda(t)},
\end{equation}
where $t=e^{i\theta}$ parametrizes the circle $S^1$.
I can then Fourier expand to obtain any element of $\Omega U(1)$ in the form
\begin{equation}
e^{i\sum_n \lambda_{n}e^{in\theta}}.
\end{equation}
However, if I set all the $\lambda_n$ to zero, I obtain the identity of $LU(1)$. This seems to me to contradict the fact that $LU(1)$ is not path connected, since all elements of $LU(1)$ are continuously connected to its identity element. Could someone explain?

Comment: Two remarks: 1/ Why do you write $S^1$ and $U(1)$ differently? It's the same thing. 2/ $LX \simeq \Omega X \times X$ is not a general fact; it happens to be true for $X = U(1)$ but not all the time (it's not clear if you believe it's a general fact or not). In general there's only a fibration $\Omega X \to LX \to X$.

Comment: @Najib: in the context of loop spaces and loop groups it's confusing to denote $S^1$ and $U(1)$ with the same symbol since they play different roles. The $S^1$ that you use to take loop spaces doesn't know it's a Lie group.

Comment: @Najib: I should have been clearer about your second point. Have edited that part, with info from an older answer by Qiaochu, which discusses related matters-http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979857/when-is-the-free-loop-space-simply-connected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda(t)$ does not necessarily have a Fourier series because it is not necessarily a periodic function. The condition on $\lambda(t)$ that makes $e^{i \lambda(t)}$ represent a function $S^1 \to U(1)$ is not that $\lambda(t + 2\pi) = \lambda(t)$ but that

$$\lambda(t + 2\pi) = \lambda(t) + 2 \pi k$$

for some integer $k$ (the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of $\lambda$). The different values of $k$ label the different path components of the loop group, so when you implicitly assume that $k = 0$ you only end up in one component.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. Would it be safe to use the same explanation when $U(1)$ is replaced by $G$, where $G$ is a non-simply connected, nonabelian Lie group?

Comment: @Meer: it's unclear to me what you mean by "the same explanation" in that case.

Comment: I think I'll write it explicitly: say I replace $U(1)$ in my question by another path connected but not simply connected group $G$, which is nonabelian. I would obtain that $LG$ is not path connected. Then, expressing the elements of $LG$ as $e^{i\lambda _a(t) T^a}$, and expanding in Fourier modes I will find that $LG$ is path connected, which is a contradiction. The source of this contradiction is again that I have not taken into account that $\lambda(t)$ is not necessarily periodic, correct?

Comment: @Meer: yes, that's right, although the Fourier expansion thing isn't a key feature of the original problem anyway. You could also have just said "but I can multiply $\lambda(t)$ by a constant and send that constant to $0$, which connects it to zero," and the problem with that argument is that the condition above, for $k \neq 0$, is not invariant under scaling (unlike periodicity).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I believe the general solution for $\lambda(t)$ in this problem is $\lambda(t)=\lambda_n e^{in\theta} + k\theta, $since this satisfies $\lambda(\theta + 2\pi)=\lambda(\theta) + 2\pi k$, am I correct?

Comment: @Meer: yes, that's right.